# SSL certificate error by intermediate/chain certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, chain

found a website that uses legal certificate (signed by thawte) but all browser will refuse it. I don't understand why.
Suppport by thawte told me there are two certificates for one domain and send me this https://www.sslshopper[dot]com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=donaubuero.de .
Can anybody explain me why the certificate chain above thawte is broken? And why the certificate of donaubuero[dot]de is invalid?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

On your webserver, you need to install both the site certificate and the chain of the certificates, which links your certificate to the root certificates which are in the browsers.

The chain certificate should be provided by your SSL provider.

How to do it, you need to check your web server documentation. Sometime you need just to add in the SSL configuration, sometime you need to chain it with your site certificate.

ADDENDUM:

You have a certificate, probably signed by a level 3 certificate. But there are many level 3 certificates (and good security practice "requires" that such certificates are updated frequently [the 3 level CA sign automatically certificates, the root CA are stored offline, and seldom, and in a more controlled way, they sign a level 2 certificate]. So browsers cannot store all level 3 certificates.

The protocol so, requires that you provide also the chain from root to your certificate. So browser check if root is trusted (by browser) and check if the various levels are trusted by previous level of certificate. In such manner, he will know that your certificate is trustfully.

The order in the chain is important, and the some implementation of SSL requires chain plus the site certificate (as two files, e.g. Apache), but other requires the full chain (chain appended to the site certificate, so one file, many email server). On some browser the order of certificates in the chain matter (mobile browsers are more picky).

This site has a maybe better explanation then my post: https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/

Comment: thanks for your answer. you think the failure is on the server and  not by thawte? I understand your explanation.
Because iam not owner or admin of the site iam not able to edit something. i just want to understand the misstake. because all i can check manualy as user seems to be ok.

Comment: How to you install a SSL certificate for your site? Check precisely the instructions. Maybe they requires a complete (with chain) certificate, or maybe there were an additional field. I add some more explanation on the answer.

Comment: thanks for your answers. You show me, that i've to train my english.